# Git Bash Command on Windows, yarn command not found

Tags: node.js, github

I following this online tutorial on downloading and installing web files from GIT HUB. I got down to the topic: Starting Our Static Website, there I'm prompted to enter the commands to download and install the web files. However, when I enter the command yarn install, I get the following prompt: bash: yarn: command not found

How can this problem be resolved?

I'm using GIT Bash command prompt on Windows 10.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably just did not install yarn yet.
Have a look at the yarn installation for Windows here:

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/

Comment: there is a raeal issue with yarn on windows - check out the answer by: user10517109

Comment: it's a convenient `brew install yarn` on macOS

Comment: i tried to install the msi file on windows. but still said that yarn command is not found. so i tried npm install -g yarn command and it worked.

Answer (score 80):

If you are using Mintty (Bash) then you simply do `npm install -g yarn`

Comment: This worked fine on just Mac terminal or iTerm as well not only using Mintty Bash

Comment: Confirming this works on MINGW64 (Git Bash) & Mintty Bash for Windows.  Note that it will not work if the `-g` is omitted.

Answer (score 14):

The official Yarn setup does not tell you you need to restart your computer, but you actually have to before you can use it from your shell. So, install it from

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

then restart your PC and you should be able to run `yarn` from your console.

Comment: No need to restart PC now, just reopen terminal

Answer (score 14):

I followed the **official yarn installation for windows** but is loading a page no found on github

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.22.17/yarn-1.22.17.msi

so I had to the manual way which is adding the path into the **environment variables**

*asuming you already have installed npm, if you are not sure type in the terminal `npm -v`*

1. install yarn on the terminal using `npm install --global yarn`
2. check the yarn packages has been installed on
   `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn`
3. if you can see the package on your `node_modules` you just need to add the bin folder that is inside the yarn into your **environment variables**
4. On the Windows taskbar, right-click the Windows icon and select System.
5. In the Settings window, under Related Settings, click Advanced system settings.
   [image]
6. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
   [image]
7. Click on Edit and add `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn`
   [image]
8. Press `ok` save open a new terminal and try running `yarn -v`

Answer (score 11):

#### Working in Visual Studio Code?

1. Open a new terminal

   - Click "**Terminal**" → "**New Terminal**"

     or
   - Simply use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick)

     - (this backtick button is on the left of the 1 key and below Esc)
2. Once the Terminal is active, install Yarn by running `npm install -g yarn`.
3. Verify the installation was successful by running `yarn --version`.

Comment: Not working in Windows 11.

Answer (score 6):

Try to type `yarn.cmd` on git bash, it should work fine.
for example: `yarn.cmd --version`.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

What resolved this for me was repairing my Node install:

1. Go to *Add or remove programs*
2. Search for "Node.js"
3. Choose *Modify*
4. Choose *Next* and then *Repair*

After doing that I was able to run yarn without issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you install yarn through MSI on windows10, and the software installed on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin`, but the path set in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Yarn\.bin`, so change the path(both user and system) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin`.

Comment: Do you mean change Environment variables paths?

Comment: @RuslanKorkin yes

Answer (score 1):

Please check first that yarn is install or not globally

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
```

If there is, then add this to your environment variable

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install `yarn wizard` first in order to run commands related to `yarn`.Click on the below link to start the download automatically:
https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the same issue on git bash. However when i tried the same in command prompt it worked!

**on bash** - $ yarn add axios
bash: yarn: command not found

**on command prompt** -
yarn add v1.22.5
....
[1/4] Resolving packages...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with Yarn and certain environments. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5349) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and for me install yarn by the installer

From the yarn official website [Yarn Official website](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable)

Answer (score 0):

Read through this if nothing helps:

> https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-yarn

for me i had to add environment variables as npm did not install in the "correct"/standard folder

```
On Windows, the output of the npm config get prefix command will look something like: C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm.

To update the PATH on a Windows machine, you have to:

Open the start search and type in env and then click "Edit the system environment variables"
Then click "Environment Variables"
Edit the Path variable and add the output you got from the npm config get prefix command.
The path should look like C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm (make sure to replace the Your_User_name placeholder with your actual username).
```

Answer (score -1):

If you **don't have npm**, you can do the following (taken from [yarn installation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable) instructions):

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this command on macbook
`brew install yarn`