# Git bash "bash: yarn: command not found"

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, git-bash

Recently, in my git bash no longer working yarn, giving me the error `bash: yarn: command not found`, as if it was never installed.

But as you can see in the attached [photo](https://paste.pics/54cf5f8e0e314cee4ae887eb068a670c), it is present.
I also tried to reinstall the package but still nothing...

This problem coincides with the installation of [IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and I think the problem may come from here, however I have not found anything useful on the internet.

Comment: IntelliJ has nothing to do with your Git Bash's PATH, and you should ideally use WSL2 rather than Git Bash nowadays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48997825/6309):

- check your path (`echo $PATH` in your bash session).
  Said path should reference `/C/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/yarn/bin`
- if not, [install yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable) through `npm install --global yarn` (global installation)

Comment: Thanks! I added the path and now it works

Comment: @SaverioRandazzo Perfect, well done!