# run yarn through cron

Tags: shell, cron, yarnpkg

I am trying to run a shell script named **start.sh** Through cron. it has below code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/azureuser/ui/frontend
yarn start
```

Below is a cron command.

```
* * * * * /home/azureuser/start.sh > cron-script.log 2>&1
```

When script runs I get error `yarn command not found` in file.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385413/git-bash-bash-yarn-command-not-found)

Comment: Tried that solution. Yarn is installed globally and still I gave the $PATH. But same issue. `yarn --version` command is working fine from any directory